# Cordova/Phonegap + Restful Api service + POST method

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, cordova

Can someone please put some light on how to connect your Cordova App to WebServices hosted on a server.

- Method: POST method
- URL: http://192.168.1.20:3030/Service1.svc
- Service Method: Login

Here's what I have been trying(Username-Password verification):

```
function GetLogin() {

        var UName = "12345678";
        var UPassword = "12345678";
        var jData = { UserName: UName, Password: UPassword };
        alert('1');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.1.20:3030/Service1.svc/AmalatLogin",
            data: JSON.stringify(jData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            processdata: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Start");
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg.ResponseMessage.toString();
                alert("End");
            }
        });
    }
```

The above code is the javascript part. I have simply called the onClick="GetLogin()" on the submit button.
The problem is the code runs when the html file is being open using localhost( i.e. "http : //(localhost)/ aaa.html" (without spaces) or even by using Google Postman), but fails to do so when I run it from the directory(as in C:\www\aaa.html).
I have been searching for the solution everywhere. Please put some light on whether this is the limitation of technology or do I need to add some plugins.

Basically alert('1') is showing, other alerts are not.

They are all in same network

Comment: And when you inspect your JS error log console, do you see any warnings/errors? My guess is that your JS isn't loading at all in the hard drive path scenario.. maybe include your <script> tag for loading the JS/jQuery library in comments, or try messing with that src value to be 100% certain that it is loading (e.g. maybe even download a copy of the .js files and load those locally too, just in case you're trying to pull those from the cloud)

Comment: nope, no errors whatsoever

Comment: Yep, "$" just doesn't exist because your JS isn't loading. In your debugger, look @ the network connections to see if the JS file loads. Maybe also share the line of HTML with the <script> loading the JS/Cordova library.